# What is the best way to run postgresql in k8s with master-slave mode?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, database-replication

We want to run postgresql in k8s with master-slave mode, what is the best way to do this?

IMO

1. Run postgresql with statefulset which pod started by order so that we can identify "master" or "slave" in startup script by pod name (such as "-0" as master and so on) and do configuration accordingly
2. Run k8s service as floating IP between master and slave, even not the same as floating IP since it's more like proxy
3. configure pod name in pg configuration file to avoid pod re-created

But there may be an issue is that the k8s service doesn't know who is the master node in backend so that it may send the write request to slave. As I known, no redirecting between master and slave in postgresql itself. Some external tools like pgpool can do the redirecting, but a little heavy.

Is there any other ways or best way to do this in 2022?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [stolon](https://github.com/sorintlab/stolon) and [cruncy data postgres operator](https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator)